# Last iteration of loop does not save

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to python. This is the part of code I unsure about:

```
i=0
while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    titles = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    i+=1

i=0
while i< len(titles):
    titles[i] = titles[i].translate(None, 'absdefghijklmnopqEUR rstuvwxyz;&Â£')
    i+=1

goldah = []

i=0
while i< len(titles):
    titles = map(float, titles)
    goldah = titles[i] * exchange
    goldah = "%.2f" % goldah
    print goldah
    i+=1
```

Which outputs

```
2.87
4.31
5.75
7.19
8.62
10.06
11.50
12.94
14.37
17.25
20.12
23.00
25.87
28.75
34.50
43.12
57.50
86.24
114.99
143.75
172.50
229.99
287.49
344.99
431.24
```

Only the last iteration of one or all of these loops saves. So when I try to call the variable `goldah` back later in the code like this: `goldah[2]` it does not give me the second value in the list but gives me the second character on the last value. Sorry I'm new to python.

Comment: I really don't understand your first two loops, it just overwrites the `titles` variable each cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the last part to

```
goldah = []

i=0
while i< len(titles):
    titles = map(float, titles)
    goldahtemp = titles[i] * exchange
    goldahtemp = "%.2f" % goldahtemp
    print goldahtemp
    goldah.append(goldahtemp)
    i+=1
```

That is because you are changing the value of `goldah` in every iteration and not actually storing it. You will have to use a temporary variable and append the results to a list.